# How do I split a CR-delimited string into multiple lines and append id to each new line?

Tags: text-processing, aix

I have a file where the lines are partitioned by internal carriage returns,
like the below:

```
EMP|123|10\rINFO|JOHN|SMITH|M|01/12/1980\rADDR|125|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
EMP|456|10\rINFO|DAVID|PIRT|M|02/12/1980\rADDR|257|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
EMP|789|10\rINFO|JENN|MCKENZI|F|03/12/1980\rADDR|389|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
```

Note that the portions of the lines between the CRs
are further delimited by `|` characters.

I want to break each line into separate lines at the CR characters. 
Then each *new* line
(i.e., a line formed by replacing a CR with a newline character)
should start with the Id (the second `|`-delimited field)
from the original line.

Expected Output:

```
EMP|123|10
123|INFO|JOHN|SMITH|M|01/12/1980
123|ADDR|125|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
EMP|456|10
456|INFO|DAVID|PIRT|M|02/12/1980
456|ADDR|257|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
EMP|789|10
789|INFO|JENN|MCKENZI|F|03/12/1980
789|ADDR|389|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
```

The Id is repeated so we can know that each group of three lines in the output belong to the same (one) input line.

I tried the below command, but it only replaced the CRs with newlines;
I am not sure how to append the Id to new lines

```
tr '\r' '\n' < test.txt > new.txt
```

output:

```
EMP|123|10
INFO|JOHN|SMITH|M|01/12/1980
ADDR|125|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
EMP|456|10
INFO|DAVID|PIRT|M|02/12/1980
ADDR|257|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
EMP|789|10
INFO|JENN|MCKENZI|F|03/12/1980
ADDR|389|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$ awk -F '\r' '{
  print $1; 
  split($1,a,"|"); 
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print a[2] "|" $i;
}' file
EMP|123|10
123|INFO|JOHN|SMITH|M|01/12/1980
123|ADDR|125|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
EMP|456|10
456|INFO|DAVID|PIRT|M|02/12/1980
456|ADDR|257|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
EMP|789|10
789|INFO|JENN|MCKENZI|F|03/12/1980
789|ADDR|389|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
```

Comment: Thank you it helped , but i have 1 more question how do i add another string to line for example a[3] also like 123|10|..

Comment: @PhaneendraPavuluri you mean like `a[2] "|" a[3] "|" $i` ? you can just concatenate strings

Answer (score 0):

In sed:

```
sed ':loop; s/^\([^|]*|\)\([^|]*|\)\([^\r]*\)\r/\1\2\3\n\2/; t loop'
```

It’s a (somewhat) simple substitution:
Match a pattern that consists of all the characters through
(i.e., up to and including) the first `\r` in the buffer. 
Break it into three capture groups:

- Everything through (i.e., up to and including)
  the first `|` in the buffer. 
  This will be `EMP|` for every line in your file.
- Everything after that, through (i.e., up to and including)
  the next (i.e., second) `|` in the buffer. 
  This will be `123|`, `456|` or `789|` in your file.
- Everything after that, up to (but *not* including)
  the first `\r` in the buffer.

Then it replaces the above with

- The three capture groups (`\1\2\3`);
  i.e., everything up to (but not including) the first `\r` in the buffer,
- A newline, and
- The second capture group (`\2`); i.e., the id and the `|`.

Then the rest of the buffer
(everything *after* the first `\r` in the buffer) is left in place,
so it falls after the repeated id on the newly created line.

Then, if the above match and **s**ubstitute succeeded
(`t` is **test** and goto if success), go back and try it again.

An aspect of this that might not be obvious to the beginner is that,
even after we have inserted a newline `\n` into the buffer
with a **s**ubstitute command, thereby creating a new line,
`sed` still operates on the entire buffer
(***including*** the internal / embedded newline character)
and not just the ‘new line’ (i.e., the portion after the newline). 
So, `sed` reads the first line,

```
EMP|123|10\rINFO|JOHN|SMITH|M|01/12/1980\rADDR|125|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
```

into the buffer. 
After the `s` command is executed for the first time, the *buffer* contains

```
EMP|123|10
123|INFO|JOHN|SMITH|M|01/12/1980\rADDR|125|BRIDGE RD|COLUMBUS|OH
```

and so the next iteration of the `s` command matches

- `\1` = `EMP|`,
- `\2` = `123|`, and
- `\3` = `10
  123|INFO|JOHN|SMITH|M|01/12/1980`
  (including the newline that was inserted in the first iteration).

Warning: This may make a mess
if there is a `\r` before the second `|` in an input line.

Comment: Can you please let me know hot to validate if we are parsing correctly by using above answered commands